# Pass JSON string via POST to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a page that is part of CRUD on which I can edit my data and send it to Update action of my php app. Basically, it is a HTML form with input fields. 
On this page I'm trying to implement some kind of drag-n-drop list arrangement via jQuery plugin. After sorting elements I create an array by js script that holds my hierarchy and it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "John"
    },
    [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Bill"
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "name": "Ann"
        }
    ],
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "Sally"
    },
    {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Tom"
    }
]
```

Now, how can I pass this array from javascript to my update action via POST with the rest of my form so I can store it in DB in a proper JSON format?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can create a single JS object containing all your data (your form data and your hierarchical array).
Afterwards, you can send that using jQuery `.ajax()` method or `.post()` method.

Querying form inputs using jquery

```
var formValues = {
    nameField1: $(field1Selector).val(),
    nameField2: $(field2Selector).val(),
    //(...) the remaining fields

    //variable holding your array
    arrangement: dragAndDropArray
 };
```

Then, you can send that request to the server by

```
$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: formValues //here you're setting the payload of your POST request
});
```

here's the [documentation for the .ajax() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**Option 2**

Another option is to create a hidden input field inside your form, and set its value to the JSON string of your JS array.

Adding a hidden field to your form like

```
<input type="hidden" id="hierarchical-array-input" name="hierarchivalArr" />
```

Then, every time you update your array, you want to set the value of the hidden input like so:

```
$('#hierarchical-array-input').val(JSON.stringify(hierarchicalArr));
```

You need to handle the values in your PHP on both cases. I suggest you try it out and debug how the PHP is parsing the data.

**Note**

You can also use the first method with a plugin that queries the form and generates a JS object for you. Like,

[jquery form serialize JSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)

Comment: Looks like Option 2 is what I am looking for. Thanks, I will give it a try.